# ProgressRing is stuck when a lot of UI update in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

There is a TreeView in the Window. I want to load TreeViewItems from ItemsSource at a event, at the same time showing the ProgressRing(MahApps.Metro.Controls).

But the ProgressRing is always stuck.

I use multithread&Dispatcher process ItemsSource loading, also not work.

XAML:

```
...
<Button Name="startButton" Content="Start" Click="Start"/>
<controls:ProgressRing x:Name="p1" IsActive="False"></controls:ProgressRing>
<TreeView x:Name="treeView1"></TreeView>
...
```

CS:

```
private void Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem root = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Root", IsExpanded = true };
    treeView1.Items.Add(root);

    p1.IsActive = true;

    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        // Main work
        InitTree(root, "D:\\");

        startButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
        (ThreadStart)delegate() {
            p1.IsActive = false;
        });
    });

    thread.Start();
}

private void InitTree(TreeViewItem item, string dir)
{
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);

    foreach (string subdir in dirs)
    {
        startButton.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
        (ThreadStart)delegate()
        {
            TreeViewItem subItem = new TreeViewItem() { Header = subdir, IsExpanded= true };
            item.Items.Add(subItem);
            InitTree(subItem, subdir);
        });
    }
}
```

What I have read&try:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
*Professional WPF Programming*, Chapter 31. MultiThread

Comment: Can you please post some code so that we can see what the problem is.. both C# and XAML

Comment: You sure you don't have other code blocking the UI?

Comment: First, try `DispatcherPriority.Background` rather than `ApplicationIdle`. Does it help?

Comment: @all I have found the reason, and the code above is correct. Thank you!

Comment: @san, consider deleting your question then.

Comment: Don't delete it. Post the solution as an answer to this question and select it as an answer. This way the knowledge can be shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
foreach (string subdir in dirs)
{
    startButton.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
    (ThreadStart)delegate()
    {
        TreeViewItem subItem = new TreeViewItem() { Header = subdir, IsExpanded= true };
        item.Items.Add(subItem);
        InitTree(subItem, subdir);
    });
}
```

to

```
foreach (string subdir in dirs)
{
    TreeViewItem subItem = new TreeViewItem() { Header = subdir, IsExpanded= true };

    startButton.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
    (ThreadStart)delegate()
    {
        item.Items.Add(subItem);
    });

    InitTree(subItem, subdir);
}
```

will be better.